# How do I force Openssl to update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, rvm, homebrew

I have been trying to use this command to install the railsapp with stripe/devise, etc using this command:

```
rails new clients -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb -T
```

And when I do I get this error:

```
apply  https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I have been following the instructions here: http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html to try and troubleshootand here is what has happened so far:

- Reinstall RVM (didn't work, still showed my OpenSSL version as: `OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011`
- Tried to install w/ brew and it says that OpenSSL is already installed

If I had any hear left I would have torn it out by now. I would greatly appreciate ANY help on this, below are my versions of anything relevant:

```
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

Rails 3.2.12

OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011

rvm 1.19.1 (master)

Homebrew 0.9.4
```

Comment: You can get help directly from the RVM team using the IRC (Internet Relay Chat) channel #rvm on irc.freenode.net:
http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm
If you’ve never used IRC, it’s worthwhile to figure out how to use IRC because the RVM team is helpful and friendly.

Comment: Be sure to review the instructions at http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html, notably using rvm with "rvm get stable --autolibs=enable" (the autolibs flag is important).

Comment: Do you have both MacPorts and Homebrew installed? Have you tried removing OpenSSL using Homebrew and reinstalling? Run 'brew doctor' before anything.

Comment: When I run `rvm get stable --autolibs=enable` I get two errors: `Can not automatically remove lines with 'rvm_autolibs_flag=' from '/etc/rvmrc', please clean it manually.
    Can not automatically remove lines with 'rvm_configure_env' from '/etc/rvmrc', please clean it manually.` are those concerning?

Comment: I only have homebrew, not macports.

Comment: After running: rvm install ruby-2.0.0 I get: `Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby -d /usr/local/rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.3/setup.rb --verbose',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log` Gist of log is here: https://gist.github.com/frankjos/06c5c3787e15387b52b1

Comment: You'll need to get help from the RVM team on IRC. Can you do that?

Comment: I am running into the same problem... https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
rvmsudo rvm get head
rvm autolibs homebrew
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
rvm reinstall 2.0.0
```

The error from rubygems is harmless.

Comment: Here is the output from step 2: `$ rvm autolibs homebrew

A RVM version 1.19.1 (master) is installed yet 1.19.1 (stable) is loaded.
Please do one of the following:
  * 'rvm reload'
  * open a new shell
  * 'echo rvm_auto_reload_flag=1 >> ~/.rvmrc' # for auto reload with msg.
  * 'echo rvm_auto_reload_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc' # for silent auto reload.`

Comment: I ran this and still get version OpenSSL 0.9.8r afterwards.

Comment: I hate to be such a n00b, but what do you mean read the outputs?

Comment: can you show the output of 'rvm remove 2.0.0; rvm --debug install 2.0.0'

Comment: Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/frankjos/fc95a98e46b6f5f85a72 I REALLY appreciate your help!

Comment: so according to https://gist.github.com/frankjos/fc95a98e46b6f5f85a72#file-output-L32 it's configured with `openssl` - did you try after: `rvm use 2.0.0 --default`

Comment: Unfortunately, yes: `$ rvm use 2.0.0 --default
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011`

Comment: you need to check if you still have the problem not if openssl version is changed: `rails new clients -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb -T`

Comment: Just ran it again and still getting this error: `https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)` Is there any way that I can run this with debug info?

Comment: it fails because it used old ruby, you need either reinstall that old ruby (`rvm reinstall 1.9.3`) or switch fully to the new one.